# JOptionPane.showInputDialog Changing the ´cancel´ Button

Tags: joptionpane

So I'm trying to get a number input from a player in an RPG/survival type game, using showInputDialog to present the options, prompting the user to input a number. My problem is, I get a fatal error if they press `cancel`.
This is my current code:

```
    String typeReader;
        do{
            typeReader = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(options);
        }while(typeReader.isEmpty());
        if (typeReader.isEmpty())
            typeReader = "0";
        charType = Integer.parseInt(typeReader);
```

and this is the error I get:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
         at Game.main(Game.java:66)
    Java Result: 1
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 14 seconds)
```

Ideally, if a user presses `cancel` the program would just read it as an empty String:

```
    typeReader = "";
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

OK, you seem to be pretty new to this ;-)
First, you won't need the loop. Just write

```
String typeReader = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(options);
```

If the user clicks "Cancel", `typeReader` will be `null` afterwards. `null` is not an object, so you cannot call `isEmpty()` on it and you get the NullPointerException. Instead, you should check for `null`:

```
if (typeReader != null) {
    ...
}
```

You should read the [Oracle tutorial on dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and maybe also the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-).